# Android- Sliding conflict between scrollview and horizontal recycler view

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, scrollview, conflict

I faced the scrolling issue between scrollview and and horizontal recycler view. In Fragment, there have a scrollview wrapping 2 horizontal recycler view. Sometimes want to slide recycler view but system can't detect as well and it will trigger scrollview to slide up or down. It's very difficult for me to scroll the recycler view.
Below Image

[image]

```
    <ScrollView
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
                android:text="Journals"
                android:textColor="@color/v2_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/v2_text_color" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
                android:text="Editor's Pick"
                android:textColor="@color/v2_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/v2_text_color" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/editorRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_showMore"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
                android:text="Show All"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#696969" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`** instead of **`ScrollView`**

And use **`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`** to  your **`RecyclerView`**

Change your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/gray" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
            android:text="Journals"
            android:textColor="@color/v2_text_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/v2_text_color" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
            android:text="Editor's Pick"
            android:textColor="@color/v2_text_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/v2_text_color" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/editorRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tv_showMore"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
            android:text="Show All"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#696969" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: its descendantFocusability will affect?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues when you use a Recyclerview inside a scrollview/nestedscrollview. The views are not recycled and will affect the overall performance of the app(If you have lots of data)
If you are trying to implement  multiple horizontal swipes and to be able to vertically swipe the layout, the best practise would be to use "Nested Recyclerview"

Basically what it does is "we will have a vertical recyclerview and each item of the vertical recyclerview will be a horizontal recyclerview"
You can refer this [project](https://github.com/jeffreyliu8/Nested-RecyclerView)

I follow this pattern and have used it in multiple projects

Hope that helps